# PHP Header move up one directory?

Tags: php, html

How do I specify a file redirect to a file one level above the current file in PHP? Here is my schematic so far:

```
-landing.html
-ajax
  -checkLogin.php
```

`checklogin.php`has the following code in it:

```
header("location:dashboard.html");
```

This obviously doesn't work since `landing.php` is one level above. How can I select a file one directory above? I already tried `..landing.php`, but seems like it will only take filenames.

Comment: For starters, you're missing a slash, ie `../landing.html`

Comment: You mean `../landing.php`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should really use absolute paths (at least relative to your document root).

Consider if you move `checkLogin.php` a directory deeper…

Any of the follow won't have a problem.

```
header("Location: /landing.html");
// or
header("Location: http://www.example.com/landing.html");
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as it will let me.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer will take you to the root of the domain, not 1 folder up as specified.

To go one folder up:

```
header("Location: ../landing.html");
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I think it is because you forgot the `/` after the `..`</strike>

```
header("Location: ../landing.php");
```

**Update:** As noted in comments, this is not up to [**specification**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30), and should be an absolute URI. Another method if you can't get the absolute path for some reason is to use:

```
$parent = dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header("Location: $parent/landing.php");
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 "The field value consists of a single **absolute URI.**"

Comment: s/landing\.php/landing\.html

Comment: @zerkms A pedantic programmer would certainly use an absolute URI whereas the pragmatic know that modern user agents can interpret a relative URL just fine

Comment: @zerkms this is a "strict" format. Browsers will still follow it as expected.

Comment: @doitlikejustin: this is a **specification**. Do you expect browsers to follow HTML specification? And what about HTTP?

Comment: @zerkms Expect... no, hope... yes.

Comment: @doitlikejustin: well, programming is not about hoping. At least I don't see how "hopes" may help developers. /me went praying for his software to work

Comment: @zerkms that too. Can't wait to see [this draft](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics/?include_text=1) realised so we can put this argument to bed

Comment: Ok, now agreeing with you. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which helped me redirect back to the Root(Home) directory.

```
<?php

    header('Refresh:0 , url=/ROOT_DIR/');

?>
```