# PHP Redirect to another Folder - 2 Levels higher

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect to another Folder - 2 Levels higher

This is the structure

> Location 1: myforum - Loginform - getLogin.php
>
> Location 2: myforum - Table Forum - subfolder1 - subfolder2 - postform.php

Currently I am at Location 2 - postform.php... how to redirect to Location 1 - getLogin.php?

Comment: What code you've tried to redirect? Are you using javascript or php for redirection?

Comment: Same answer as [PHP Header move up one directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862482/php-header-move-up-one-directory).

Answer (score -2):

```
header("Location: ../../Loginform/getLogin.php");
```

you need to go 2 levels down to reach folder myforum and then one level up to reach loginForm.

As PeeHaa mentioned, HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs.

So relative path may or may not work. Using an absolute path will be something like this:

```
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/Loginform/getLogin.php");
```

Comment: The spec will tell you to always use full URLs for the location header.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs