# PHP header not redirecting up a directory level

Tags: php, header

There are lots of questions of similar taste, but cannot find any regarding my specifics.

I have a login.php script:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "connection.php";   

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer_Username = '$myusername' and Customer_Password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         $_SESSION['Username'] = $myusername;

    header("Location: Welcome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Username or Password is invalid";
         echo $error;
      }
   }
   ?>
```

As you can see I want to redirect the user to the Welcome.php page upon successful login.

My Welcome.php was originally located in the scripts/ folder, but it is **NO LONGER** in that folder and i have moved it too my "main" folder, and yet when I login, this error message appears:

> The requested URL /scripts/Welcome.php was not found on this server.

However, as noted, my Welcome.php file is not placed in my /scripts/ folder anymore. 
When i try and move the file into my scripts/ folder to try and get rid of the error, the message then reads :

> The requested URL scripts/scripts/Welcome.php was not found on this server.

It seems the /scripts/ part does not want to go away.....Any ideas on how I can fix this or what could have happened.... I'd like to note it was working okay before i relocated the file.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is your header will not kill the script, so everything else will run. You need to use `die('text');` right after your header, to solve this.

EDIT: See this link for help in going up a level: [PHP Header move up one directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862482/php-header-move-up-one-directory#answer-18862516)

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the problem based on the *title*, but it's not, read the question more carefully.

Comment: Edited to include a helpful link